Is It Possible to Send Local Notifications every 15 minus in MAUI IOS
Hi My requirement is i want to read data From APi,  i want to send local Notifications if data is available other wise don't send localnotification. even if the app is closed state or background.
public static void ScheduleLocalNotifications()
{
 // Request permission to display alerts and play sounds.
 UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.RequestAuthorization(UNAuthorizationOptions.Alert | UNAuthorizationOptions.Sound, async (granted, error) =>
 {
     if (granted)
     {
         //NotificationsData data = await GlobalParams.ReadNotification();
         int rem = new Random().Next(1, 100);
         //foreach (var item in data.resultnew)
         //{
             string StatusTxt = string.Empty;
             
             // Your notification content
             var content = new UNMutableNotificationContent
             {
                 Title = "Activated",
                 Body = "Next No: "+rem,
                 Sound = UNNotificationSound.Default
             };

             // Trigger to repeat every 5 minutes
             var trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger.CreateTrigger(120, true);

             // Create a notification request
             var request = UNNotificationRequest.FromIdentifier("FiveMinuteNotification", content, trigger);

             // Schedule the notification
             UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.AddNotificationRequest(request, (err) =>
             {
                 if (err != null)
                 {
                     //Console.WriteLine($"Error scheduling notification: {err.LocalizedDescription}");
                 }
                 
             });
         //}
     }
     else
     {
         
     }
 });
}

i tried above code but its not updating notification message every time its sending same message

Have you set notification request permissions in your project? (although the documentation is Xamarin.iOS related, the same applies to MAUI)

Yes I have set, i am getting notification but its not updating. every time it is sending same notification.

The reason for the problem is because when you set CreateTrigger to true, the same content is called every time the App sends notification, and the rem random number in the content is fixed, which causes the same value to be displayed every time.
When you set CreateTrigger to false, the ScheduleLocalNotification method is rerun every time you send notification, rem regenerates the random number assigned to content, so the notification received will be different each time.

Notification is Comming in every interval But the problem is Same notification is came, not chnaging the text actually. I used random number in the content boy but for every notification  its comming same message body what ever i got first notification its repeating every interval time . its not updating the message body.

You can check my updated answer.

Yes it is coming now after set to false but the problem it its coming only 2 times after that the notification not receiving. why ?

During my testing, CreateTrigger(120, false); can receive multiple notifications normally, note that the difference between true and false is whether the notification is automatically sent repeatedly. You have to make sure that every time you tap the send notification button, the app goes to the background.

is there any other example. my requitement is i need to send local notification frequently with every specific time even the app is in foreground / background or the app is not running also.

In iOS, notifications cannot be received when the app is in the foreground, but can be received when the app is in the background or not running. In addition, when the parameter in CreateTrigger() is set to true, it is impossible to send different notification content each time.
